# How do i get current Branch path from Source control explorer using VS package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, vsix

I have created VS extension that creates a menu command on Source control explorer by right click on that it open custom form,Now i want to display current TFS path(from where user right click) in that custom form.Same as TFS "Branching and Merging => Branch" Source Path.

Any help Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the VersionControlExplorerExt object with its properties SelectedItems, CurrentFolderItem, etc. From a package it would be something like:

```
  private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt versionControlExt;
     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExplorerExt versionControlExplorerExt;
     EnvDTE.DTE dte;

     try
     {
        dte = base.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;

        versionControlExt = dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") 
           as Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt;

        versionControlExplorerExt = versionControlExt.Explorer;

        MessageBox.Show(versionControlExplorerExt.CurrentFolderItem.LocalPath);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The extensibility for Source Control Explorer should be exposed through the [VersionControlExt.Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.versioncontrolexplorerext.aspx) class. The [VersionControlExt.Explorer.SelectedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.versioncontrolexplorerext.selecteditems.aspx) property should contain the server paths for the selected items. Here is an [old blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2006/02/03/524312.aspx) that might also have some useful information for writing extensions.